# Passing events back from Angular.dart view to Controller/Component code

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to figure out how to pass event parameters from a component back to my class handling the event.

In my case, I'm trying to register a "KeyPressed" event in a component, like so:

```dart
<textarea ng-keypress="cmp.KeyPressed(event)" rows="1" cols="100"></textarea>
```

And the code handling the event looks like this:

```dart
void KeyPressed(event) {
   print("keypressed!");
}
```

Whenever a key is pressed, the KeyPressed() function fires. However, the "event" being passed in is null. How do I pass in event parameters correctly, and what is the event type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$event`

```dart
<textarea ng-keypress="cmp.KeyPressed($event)" rows="1" cols="100"></textarea>
```

Comment: Great! It's working and returns an instance of a 'KeyboardEvent' class. Is this info referenced in any documentation? I've looked all over and couldn't find anything.